# IF statement not behaving as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show a user's full name if the user is logged in. If not, the text "Login" should be displayed.

This is what I have so far:

```
session_start();

$session = $_SESSION['username'];

include "config.php";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from user");    
while($d=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if($d['status']=='online' and $_SESSION['username'] == $d['username'])
    {
        $full_names = $d['full_name'];

        echo $full_names;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Login";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all you need to read about the SQL `WHERE` clause (and right after that, read something about SQL injection). After that, think about how much sense it makes to iterate over *every single* user when you want a *specific one* with a unique name.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using WHERE to narrow that query down to the username(s) you want? Without that, this will not scale well.

Comment: While you're at it, look into PDO or MySQLi before someone here yells at you.

Comment: Why does this question get downvotes? Obviously he's a beginner, but it's a programming question and he showed what he tried... All the relevant code is there.

Comment: yeah I think this website is a place to ask and provide solutions. If there is one wrong of my questions please justified. I know when it is wrong, I'm not going to post this here.

Comment: The downvotes are unnecessary, but please consider what is being said here, @X-men -- you need to start using PDO, soon there won't be any choice. Also, the looping approach is not good -- the `WHERE` statement is critical. You've accepted a solution that will not help you improve as a programmer, and I hope you'll read and consider the information in my answer. I don't care about the points, I really am here to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an SQL `WHERE` (as @ThiefMaster mentioned), but just to answer your question:

```
$full_names = false;
while($d=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if($d['status']=='online' and $_SESSION['username'] == $d['username']) {
        $full_names = $d['full_name'];

        echo $full_names;
    }
}

if(!$full_names) {
  echo "Login";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show how to do it with `WHERE`? This answer may give the desired result, but I don't think it's is very helpful.

Comment: @Mischa The title of his question was about if/else, so that's what I answered. The method I posted is useful in other situations, and now he knows it. I was honestly expecting someone else to post a WHERE example. But since no one else did, I did.

Comment: -1 This is simply and completely bad practice, bad code, and harmful to a beginner

Comment: @Chris My policy when answering bad questions is to: 1 tell the user what they are doing wrong. But 2: I also actually answer the asked question, even though it would not be necessary if they did it properly. I do this because when I was a beginner I HATED when people would not answer what I asked - yes I should be doing it differently, but I still wanted the answer to my question!

Comment: If someone is trying to hammer a nail with a glass jar, you give them a hammer, not pointers on ways they might avoid cutting their hand if they wrap the jar in a towel.

Comment: (note: do not try this. The towel thing does not really work :p)

Comment: @Chris Wrong. I do both. I give them a hammer AND I help avoid injuries. And now you've gotten me curious about how to hammer in a nail using a glass jar... Do you know for sure the towel thing doesn't work? I wonder if filling the jar with water and making ice would work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the user *name* in session, you may want to store the id instead. That isn't as important as using a `WHERE` statement in your query to limit the results to a single row -- the user in question. This is important because as your user database grows in size, this query would become more and more inefficient. With a little simple logic, you can prevent that future problem and have a more robust architecture in the balance.

Another important note, `mysql_*` **functions are being deprecated, you should not use them.** It cannot be stressed enough that you need to start using PDO. It isn't too hard to figure out (no more so that the `mysql_*` functions!), you may as well get started with it now -- soon, `mysql_*` won't be available at all. Your code will stop working, or you'll be stuck on an old PHP version full of known security holes.

Before you refer to a key in `$_SESSION`, you should check to make sure it exists.

```
session_start();
$session_identifier = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : false;
$user_name = false;
if ($session_identifier) {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", '-username-', '-password-');
    $sql = '
        SELECT 
            full_name 
        FROM 
            users 
        WHERE 
            username = ":username"
    ';
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    if($statement->execute(array(':username'=>$session_identifier)))
        $user_name = $statement->fetchColumn();
}
```

... and then you can do this:

```
if ($user_name)
    print 'Welcome, '.$user_name;
else
    print '<a href="login.php">Login</a>';
```

**Documentation**

- `isset` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- `PDO` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php
- `PDO::prepare` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
- `PDOStatement` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php
- `PDOStatement::execute` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
- `PDOStatement::fetchColumn` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php
- `mysql_query` **DEPRECATED!** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- mySQL `SELECT` (see the `WHERE` section) - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @X-men Good! It is an uphill battle, advocating for new programmers to abandon `mysql_*` functions because so many tutorials or poor answers on sites like this continue to steer beginners in the wrong direction. PDO or mysqli are the only safe approaches going forward, so if you are learning, this is what you need to learn. The `WHERE` bit is equally important and is not at all new -- the loops you were doing solved the problem, but believe me it is not the "right" way to get the job done. Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

You should change your query to:

```
"SELECT * from user WHERE status = 'online' AND username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'"
```

Then you don't need the where loop.

You should also use mysqli rather than mysql.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated, and should not be recommended for any new code.

Comment: @Chris I know - I said that in my answer didn't I?

Comment: No, you didn't. You suggested he use it by posting an answer that contains it, no where does the word "deprecated" appear.